# Reflection can't find assembly types in Citrix

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, reflection, citrix

I have a WPF (NET 4.6) app running under Citrix where I dynamically load reports from the assemblies as long as the type has the DisplayName attribute defined.  This works fine when run from my machine or from a network share.  This does NOT work in Citrix.

```
var asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var rep = asm.GetTypes().Where(x => (typeof(Telerik.Reporting.Report)).IsAssignableFrom(x) && x.IsDefined(typeof(System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute), true)).ToList();
Reports = (rep.ToDictionary((x => (x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute), true).Single()
                    as System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute).DisplayName), (x => x)));
```

Comment: I don't know about Citrix, but have you tried logging the results of the various calls involved in order to pinpoint the problem?

Comment: I plan on it, but the way the Citrix farm is built makes this sort of thing very laborious. I don't control the Citrix machines so it take RFCs and a day or two to push something out to them.

Comment: It's failling on the GetTypes() call but I wasn't able to capture the entire exception.